# How can i get paginated results for both departure and return flights from this code

Tags: php, mysql

[image: Current code]I am trying to use this code to return flights from a table .. the json data i get is okay but i want to display the data using divs so that a client can proceed to book a flight but am stack

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';

session_start();


      $sql = "
SELECT origin
     , destination
     , departure
     , arrival
     , craftoperator
     , date
     , returndte
     , operatorlogo
     , Price 
  FROM test 
 WHERE origin = '".$_REQUEST['origin']."' 
   AND destination = '".$_REQUEST['destination']."'
   AND date = '".$_REQUEST['departure']."'
    OR returndte = '".$_REQUEST['return']."' ";



   $result = $conn->query($sql);



while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $output[]=$row;
}
print(json_encode($output));

?>
```

The image shows the desired output right now i can only see json output

[image: Image show desired output right now i can only see json output]

Comment: Have you made any attempts to do this yourself? If so, please add a copy of that code, as it will help us better understand what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Michael Thompson am adding the code I have so far

Comment: See about prepared statements and (avoidance of) sql injection. Also, your `ANDs and ORs` confuse me, so they must confuse your db too. Astute use of parentheses required,

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code is vunerable to SQL injection.

Now, to make website to use `<div>` blocks you need to return that `json_encode($data)`. Then to use those information in another file where to decode data `json_decode($data)` and to use `foreach/for` to parse each row.

Example:

```
foreach(json_decode($data, true) as $flight) {
  echo '
     <div>....</div>
  ';
}
```

Comment: Am still a little need in code so how best do i avoid SQL Injection and can i remove the json part and use php sessions to send that data to another page

Comment: Read more about `prepare()` statement for PDO / MySQLi. Never use `$_REQUEST`. You NEED to know how you will receive data (`$_POST` / `$_GET`).  Maybe use `$.ajax` to get your information. I don't recommend to keep those information in session.

Comment: So if am to modify my code to remove $_REQUEST and I use $_GET or $_POST then added prepared statements that would limit my Sq injection vulnerability?

Comment: Yes! You need to be careful with data that you are using it as query parameters. Please read more about SQL injection and how it can be avoided